# Ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{5})$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, integer-rings

I'm trying to find the ring of integers $A_L$ of $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{5})$. I know that the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and that the one of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ is $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right]$. 
I would like to say that $A_L=\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},i\right]$.

From [Integral basis of the ring of integers of an extension, given integral bases of the rings of integers of subfields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2875958/integral-basis-of-the-ring-of-integers-of-an-extension-given-integral-bases-of) I understood it is possible to say $A_L=\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right]\mathbb{Z}\left[i\right]$ using the fact the discriminants of the two integer basis are coprime (Here we use a result that is possible to find in Marcus' book).

Is there a way to find $A_L$ in a more direct way without using that result?

Comment: For what it's worth, multiplying units of the intermediate rings could give you the defining polynomial, e.g., $$\frac{-i}{2} - \frac{\sqrt 5}{2}$$ has polynomial $x^4 + 3x^2 + 1$, from which you can find its entry in the LMFDB: http://lmfdb.com/NumberField/4.0.400.1

Answer (score 2):

Write $\omega = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}2$. Then all elements $\alpha = a + bi + c\omega + di\omega$ where $a, b, c, d$ are integers. If the ring of integers is larger, there must be algebraic integers of the form 
$\alpha/2$ or $\alpha/5$ since $2$ and $5$ are the only prime divisors of the discriminant of the subring generated by $i$ and $\omega$. Now all you have to do is show that if $\alpha/2$ is an algebraic integer, then $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are divisible by $2$, and then do the same with respect to the prime $5$.

Comment: This must be in Marcus.  If $K$ is any number field generated by an algebraic integer $\alpha$, and if $\alpha$ has discriminant $D$, then any algebraic integer in $K$ is a fraction with denominator $D$, whose numerator is a ${\mathbb Z}$-linear combination of powers of $\alpha$.

Comment: I'm sorry I deleted the question just two minutes after your comment because I didn't see it and I managed to solve the problem manually. I show it in our case:
Let $ y= a+bα+c\beta+d\alpha\beta \in A_L$ with $ a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q} $. We know that $$ D(a,bα,c\beta,d\alpha\beta)= (abcd)^2 \cdot D(1,α,\beta,α\beta).$$ It follows that $ (abcd)^2 = D(a,bα,c\beta,d\alpha\beta) D(1,α,\beta,α\beta)^{-1}$ and $ D(1,α,\beta,α\beta)\in \mathbb{Z} $. So we have trivially the result.


I hope this is right and useful!